# Laravel template snippets

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, code-snippets

Is this any possibilities to make code snippets in Laravel Blade templates ?

I need to do something similar like was in Smarty - you place [tag param1="value" param2="value"] and It's going throught function tag with render specify template under it.

Comment: It is not best practice, as all business logic is supposed to exist in the controller, and the blades are supposed to be just for display. That said, to answer your question, you can still use the <?php ?> tags to define a function, then call that function using blade syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible by using either [Components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#components-and-slots) or [Include](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views). These allow you to create so called sub-views that can be called multiple times on a page with a number of parameters.

Comment: You're right, but I've also need to pass It through some function, and then send data to template.

Comment: Can't you run the function in you controller beforehand?

Comment: The idea was to create list of predefined snippets, with making specific things - like display slider.

Frontend developer place [slider id=1] tag in template, and he gets slider with picture #1.

Comment: You can actually do that. You can put php tags in your views and run php code. You even have access to Laravel models and classes. However it is recommended to put php code in your controllers.